# Is there a data structure similar to std::set in TCL?

Tags: list, data-structures, dictionary, set, tcl

TCL has a data structure called [`dict`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) which maintains a collection of key-value pairs.

Is there another data structure which maintains a collection of keys (with no values)?

If no, then maybe someone already wrote a simple adapter on [`dict`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) with empty values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the tcllib package `::struct::set`.

http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_set.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single list.

```
set example [list "key1" "key2" "key3"]
if {[lsearch -exact $example "key3"] != -1} {
    puts "found your key!"
} else {
    puts "your key is not in the list"
}
```

Maybe you should ask a more specific question to get a more accurate answer. 
An alternative for `dict` is `array` which doesn't preserve the order of keys.

Comment: You can uses `if {"key3" in $example} { ...` instead of that `lsearch` (operator introduced in 8.5).

Comment: Honestly, I thought the question was perfectly specific about what it was looking for. Lists, Maps, and Sets are all distinct data structures with different properties.

Comment: That's not a good answer since search is not O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to accumulate everything into say, `$bucket`.

Then do:

```
set uniqueItems [lsort -unique $bucket]
```